# Slowly fill SVG image with color (like progress bar) in android

Tags: android, svg

If I have a simple stroke path, like below:
[image]
I know how to animate it. What if I have a path which is constituted by a closed path, just like the below img:
[image]
I have the svg of the picture, how to animate it slowly in the direction of the arrow line, like:
[image]

Sorry for my poor english skill, hope you can understand what I mean.
Any advise will be appreciate ,Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this Lib. https://github.com/geftimov/android-pathview

Comment: @anonymous thanks for your advise , and I know the lib, but It only can animate the stroke path.

Comment: Redraw the path so it's drawn as a stroke rather than a fill.

Comment: @RobertLongson but some complex shape can't be draw well only by stroke.

Comment: And complex shapes cannot be gradually filled easily either. So which do you want to do?

Comment: Are you running in a WebView, or do you want it to run more natively such as using AnimatedVectorDrawable, or in a simple Graphics2D context?

Comment: Not in webview.